# Python - How to make a PATCH request to an API with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to make a PATCH request to an API with python. I'm really new to python. I have done some research and found out about the requests module. I making the request

```
customerImported = requests.patch(f'https://somewebsite.io/api/v1/RefNum/20IOR011673', data={'Imported': 'yes'})
print(customerImported.json())
```

like so

I get an error response from the api. which says

> {'error': 'Missing data parameter in request.'}

Here's we can do the same thing with PHP (which works!)

```
<?php
$data = http_build_query(
    [
        'data' =>
            [
              ['name' => 'Scott', 'age' => 25]
            ]
    ]
);

$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'PATCH',
    'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'content' => $data
  )
);

$result = json_decode(
  file_get_contents('https://somewebsite.io/api/v1/id/61', false, stream_context_create($options))
);
```

How can I do this python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter in `requests.patch` works like the `content` parameter in PHP
s `stream_context_create`. The API is responding with an error because it expects that the JSON object you send it will include a key called `data`. I would assume that this is what it expects:

```
customerImported = requests.patch(
    f'https://somewebsite.io/api/v1/RefNum/20IOR011673',
    data={'data': { 'Imported': 'yes'}})
```

This is a problem on the API side; nothing to do with Python. If the problem persists, try to find some documentation for the API so that you can be sure to send it data in the format it expects.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it solved the current issue. now I'm getting `{'error': 'Data should be an array of objects in valid json format.'}` So I did: `data={'data': [{"Imported": "yes"}]}` but still same error

Comment: @vajad57 The API is a REST interface implemented through JSON (at least, it really seems like it). The documentation for other languages is still useful to you; you just need to see the format of the data being sent, and the format of the data being returned. It doesn't matter what language the requests are being prepared in, so long as you understand the JSON being passed back and forth.

Comment: Using `json.dumps` fixed it :)

Comment: @vajad57 Great, glad to hear it!